# bootstrap multiselect adding custom text input

Tags: bootstrap-multiselect

I am trying to add a text box as one of the options because I am using the multiselect as a filtering element on a separate list. I want the text box to act as a free text filter.
I have tried many things but cant get this to work...

I tried enabledHTML and inserted the input box in the option however although the textbox shows it is disabled (i cant enter any text - it seems to be blocked by a parent element but I cant figure out which one)

I tried to hijack the textbox that shows up when using enableFiltering. The problem is I cant seem to disable the event which causes filtering on the list when i enter text into the textbox. I dont want that filtering to happen, just want the text to remain in the textbox ideally with a checkbox next to it and then I can handle my list filtering by referencing the textbox value.

Can anyone advise how to do this?

Comment: noone able to help with this??? I would think this is a standard "hack" someone has done before on the multi-select?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Figured it out. There's an onchange event called on all inputs in the dropdown. Blocking propogation allows me to make use of it.
So enabled HTML, added the input text box as an option.
And then bound a change event to that text box and stopped propagation.
Now I can use it.

Comment: I am trying to do this, not sure how to stop propagation using the `onChange` event according to the documentation it doesn't pass the event through it, as these are the params:  `onChange: function(option, checked, select) { }` Can you provide an example in your answer please?  I'm not able to click in the textbox and type... seems like everytime I click in the textbox it loses focus, weird.

Comment: It would be really nice if you actually showed how you solved the problem.

Comment: Hello @Gotts could post your code? I was about to ask the same question but your explanation is not clear.
How did you "bound a change event to that text box and stopped propagation"?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this is what works for me. In order to stop propagation you need to call call just **after** the multiselect is initialized or rebuilt. Otherwise, the selector won't work and it won't stop the propagation.

You can checkout [this Fiddle for a live version](http://jsfiddle.net/helenatxuhelenatxu/13ruoLd0/18/).

My code, example taken from de Docs (for live working version check the Fiddle):

```js
$(function () { 
    
     const inputTemplateOptions = {
        enableHTML: true,
        templates: {
          li: '<li><a><label style="display:inline;"></label><input type="text" class="custom-input" /></a></li>'
        }
      };
    
     $('select[multiple]').each(function() {
          const config = Object.assign(
            {},
            inputTemplateOptions,
            $(this).data('multiselect-config')
            );

          $(this).multiselect(config); // here we initialized it with our config
          
          $( "input.custom-input" ).on( "click", function() {
            event.stopPropagation();
          });
        }); 
    });
```

```html
<body>
  <select id="example-multiple-selected" multiple="multiple">
      <option value="1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="3">Option 3</option>
      <option value="4">Option 4</option>
      <option value="5">Option 5</option>
      <option value="6">Option 6</option>
  </select>
</body>
```